# How to replace namespace and prefix in element and attributes using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Input File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S2SCTCcvf:MPEDDCcvfBlkDirDeb xsi:schemaLocation='urn:MyNameSpace:xsd:pain.002.001.03 pain.002.001.03_SCT_By_FundTech.xsd' xmlns:S2SCTCcvf='urn:MyNameSpace:xsd:pain.002.001.03' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <S2SCTCcvf:SndgInst>YESBGB20</S2SCTCcvf:SndgInst>
    <S2SCTCcvf:RcvgInst>12333462</S2SCTCcvf:RcvgInst>
    <S2SCTCcvf:SrvcId>SCT</S2SCTCcvf:SrvcId>
    <S2SCTCcvf:TstCode>T</S2SCTCcvf:TstCode>
    <S2SCTCcvf:CstmrPmtStsRpt xmlns="urn:MyNameSpace:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>1510209235700400</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2015-01-02T09:23:57</CreDtTm>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>YESBGB20</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>BARCGB20</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
        </GrpHdr>
    </S2SCTCcvf:CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</S2SCTCcvf:MPEDDCcvfBlkDirDeb>
```

Required Output File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S2SDDCdvf:MPEDDCdvfBlkDirDeb xsi:schemaLocation='urn:S2SDDCdvf:xsd:$MPEDDCdvfBlkDirDeb ..\MPEDDCdvfBlkDirDeb.xsd' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:S2SDDCdvf='urn:S2SDDCdvf:xsd:$MPEDDCdvfBlkDirDeb'>
    <S2SDDCdvf:SndgInst>YESBGB20</S2SDDCdvf:SndgInst>
    <S2SDDCdvf:RcvgInst>DTU33462</S2SDDCdvf:RcvgInst>
    <S2SDDCdvf:SrvcId>SCT</S2SDDCdvf:SrvcId>
    <S2SDDCdvf:TstCode>T</S2SDDCdvf:TstCode>
    <S2SDDCdvf:CstmrPmtStsRpt xmlns="urn:MyNameSpace:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>1510209235700400</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2015-01-02T09:23:57</CreDtTm>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>BARCGB20</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>YESBGB20</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
        </GrpHdr>
    </S2SDDCdvf:CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</S2SDDCdvf:MPEDDCdvfBlkDirDeb>
```

Can you please help me with the XSLT which will convert the input file to output xml file ?

Comment: What's not working with the XSLT you've tried? perhaps you could also include that?

Answer (score 1):

You want a template rule something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="S2SCTCcvf:*" xmlns:S2SCTCcvf="old-namespace">
  <xsl:element name="S2SCTCdvf:{local-name()}" namespace="new-namespace">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

plus an identity template to match elements in other namespaces.

Comment: AFAICT, *all* the elements of the source document are in the same namespace, despite only *some* of them being prefixed.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note:**

- **All** the elements in your source XML document are in the same namespace. Some of them are prefixed, and some are not - but they are
  all in the same namespace, nevertheless.

If the structure of the source XML document is known (at least partially), you could base the transformation on that; for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:S2SCTCcvf='urn:MyNameSpace:xsd:pain.002.001.03'>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:S2SDDCdvf:xsd:$MPEDDCdvfBlkDirDeb">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::S2SCTCcvf:CstmrPmtStsRpt]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this would return something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPEDDCcvfBlkDirDeb xmlns="urn:S2SDDCdvf:xsd:$MPEDDCdvfBlkDirDeb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:MyNameSpace:xsd:pain.002.001.03 pain.002.001.03_SCT_By_FundTech.xsd">
   <SndgInst>YESBGB20</SndgInst>
   <RcvgInst>12333462</RcvgInst>
   <SrvcId>SCT</SrvcId>
   <TstCode>T</TstCode>
   <CstmrPmtStsRpt xmlns="urn:MyNameSpace:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
      <GrpHdr>
         <MsgId>1510209235700400</MsgId>
         <CreDtTm>2015-01-02T09:23:57</CreDtTm>
         <DbtrAgt>
            <FinInstnId>
               <BIC>YESBGB20</BIC>
            </FinInstnId>
         </DbtrAgt>
         <CdtrAgt>
            <FinInstnId>
               <BIC>BARCGB20</BIC>
            </FinInstnId>
         </CdtrAgt>
      </GrpHdr>
   </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</MPEDDCcvfBlkDirDeb>
```

which I believe is the exact equivalent of your requested output - with or without prefixes.